# open a file - permission denied

Tags: ruby, file

I tried to open a file in this way

```
File.open(f_name, File::CREAT | File::RDWR) do |file|

end
```

Absolute file path is passed in as filename, such as filename is

```
/mounts/dd670-6.chaos.local/cifs/tfile6
```

Get the error message

```
Permission denied - /mounts/dd670-6.chaos.local/cifs/tfile6 (Errno::EACCES)
```

And, if I go into that directory and open that file, operation can be done successfully.

Anybody has any clue?

Comment: Try running `chmod 777 /mounts/dd670-6.chaos.local/cifs/tfile6` and then re-running the program, it may still be a problem with permissions.  
For example, it often happens that you have read access but not write access (just one example), while you're trying to open it with read and write access.

Answer (score 2):

you can try change the perms before opening the file:

```
chmoded = 0
f_name = __FILE__
begin
    File.open(f_name, File::CREAT | File::RDWR) do |file|
    end
rescue => e
    File.chmod(0755, f_name) rescue nil
    chmoded += 1
    retry if chmoded < 2
    puts e.message
end
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=open-a-file-permission-denied.rb&run=true)

Comment: demo url is expired now :(